# How to use aliases for catalogs for file creation navigation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias

if I have some aliases like **Catalog1** (/home/ed/1), **Catalog2** (/home/ed/2)
I have scripts in Catalog1, and Catalog2 is for output saving, f.e. :

```
 python /home/ed/1/one.py > /home/ed/2/log1.txt
```

i need to do this:

```
 python Catalog1/one.py > Catalog2/log1.txt
```

How can I do it? 
using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with aliases, however, you could use variables:

In your .bashrc, add:

```
Catalog1='/home/ed/1'
Catalog2='/home/ed/2'
```

Reload your shell and you will be able to use it like:

```
python $Catalog1/one.py $Catalog2/log1.txt
```